# Convert base64 string to JSON .NET

Tags: c#, json, .net, base64

I'm new to C# and I have a client request with a value which is base64 encoded. I'm trying to decode the string and make use of the JSON object. Here is the function I call to decode the base64 string.

```
    public string FromBase64(string data)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(data)) return data;
        var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(data);
        return UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
    }
```

How can I convert the return value of this function or modify it to JSON so that I can parse its values?

For example, right now for the value of input value `data` `e0tleSA6ICdhYmMnLCBpc0V4aXN0czogJ3RydWUnfQ==`, the current output is `"{Key : 'abc', isExists: 'true'}"`.
The output I want is `{Key : 'abc', isExists: 'true'}`

Comment: well, what does your existing code return? we don't know what your payload is, so we don't know what is going to happen when that executes...

Comment: Can you give an example of input and expected output?

Comment: @MarcGravell I have updated the question

Comment: @zinngg what difference are you seeing? they look the same to me....

Comment: @MarcGravell The current output is of a string type but the output that I need is a JSON/Object.

Comment: @zinngg Of course it's a string. JSON is naturally a string, and you're calling `GetString(bytes)`. What you need to do is look up _deserializing_ JSON.

Comment: @zinngg You'll need to run it through a JSON deserializer, obviously; for example: https://gist.github.com/mgravell/c232664fd97fbbbdffc6560d1ed521fb

Comment: Thanks @MarcGravell. This was what I needed. I had tried to de-serialize it earlier but had got some errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a base-64 string, and you seem to what a deserialized object; so you'll need multiple steps:

- decode the base-64 to binary
- interpret the binary as text
- define an object model that matches the expected data
- deserialize the text as the object model

For example:

```cs
    static void Main()
    {
        var base64 = @"e0tleSA6ICdhYmMnLCBpc0V4aXN0czogJ3RydWUnfQ==";
        var blob = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
        var json = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(blob);
        // string: "{Key : 'abc', isExists: 'true'}"
 
        var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyPayload>(json);
        Console.WriteLine(obj.Key);
        Console.WriteLine(obj.IsExists);
    }

    class MyPayload
    {
        public bool IsExists { get; set; }
        public string Key { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I hope I understood your question correctly, here is my code example for a generic method that can create a `T` object by deserializing a base-64 string:

```
    public static T FromBase64<T>(string data)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(data))
        {
            return default;
        }
        
        var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(data);
        var parsedString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
        return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(parsedString);
    }
```

Comment: for parsedString; it gives 'Cannot convert from 'string' to JSonReader' error.

Answer (score 0):

Your code to turn the base64 into string is working properly so now you need to create a class corresponding to your JSON and deserialize the result of the method :

```
var content = FromBase64(myBase64);
var myObject = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MyObject>(content);
```